# Modify NumPy array in loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a problem with array manipulation in NumPy. If I create two arrays `x` and `y`, and do

```
x = x - y
```

I get what I expect, that is each element of `y` is subtracted from the corresponding element of `x`, and thus `x` is modified.
However, if I put this in a loop:

```
m = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
y = array([1, 1, 1])
for i in m:
    i = i - y
```

the matrix `m` remains unaltered. I am sure I am missing something very basic... How can I change the array `m` in a loop?

Answer (score 4):

This is not related with numpy matrix, but how python deal with your

```
i = i - y
```

`i - y` produces a new reference of an array. When you assigns it to name i, so i is not referred to the one it was before, but the newly created array.

The following code will meet your purpose

```
for idx, i in enumerate(m):
    m[idx] = i - y
```

Answer (score 3):

Update: I realize that the easiest thing is to do

```
m = m-y
```

This does directly what I expected!

Answer (score 0):

If working with an example where you are unable to avoid looping through the array but still want to change the row, do this

```
m = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
y = array([1, 1, 1])
for i in m:
    i -= y
```